# How to change the rate of an AVPlayer video

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

Hey I'm trying to get a video to play at a different rate (Slower). I can't seem to get it to work.

Code:

This line of code doesn't work

```
playerLayerView.player?.rate = 0.50
```

Full Code:

```
var player = AVPlayer()
var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
var playerLayerView = AVPlayerViewController()


let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Video", ofType: "mov")
let prl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
player = AVPlayer(url: prl)
playerLayerView.player = player
playerLayerView.view.frame = CGRect(.frame.width * 0.0, .frame.height * 0.0, .frame.width, .frame.height)
playerLayerView.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill.rawValue
playerLayerView.player?.rate = 0.50
player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
player.isMuted = false
page.insertSubview(playerLayerView.view, at: 0)
playerLayerView.player?.play()
```

The only why can get it to play is. If I use playImmediately and delete the .Play()

```
player.playImmediately(atRate: 0.50) //.rate = 1.50 //0.50, 0.67, 0.80, 1.0, 1.25, 1.50, and 2.0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the rate property after playerLayerView.player?.play() calling this method.

Comment: Welcome :) it happens.

Comment: Great, Work for me 